# tkinter windows losing information after switching window or virtual desktop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created GUI with tkinter and when the GUI is up & running everything is working and showing very nice. But, as soon I change to a different window (not related to the tkinter GUI) or change virtual desktop (redhat) and go back to the tkinter based GUI the window is empty, see screen shot:

[image]

All the tkinter object and information in the window is not visible anymore. Small update I removed the Yes window so it doesn't confuse and it still shows that the issue still occurs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Separator
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
import Tkinter
    
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("SMF testing...")

app_width = 670
app_height = 320

x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

# Positions the window in the center of the page.
root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(app_width, app_height, x, y))

label_id = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable=label_id, relief=RAISED)
label_msg = StringVar() 

label_id.set("Paste the id")

label_header = Label(root, text="Select Node:")
label_header.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

label_id = Label(root, text="ID:", width=10)
label_id.grid(row=2, column=0)

entry_id = Entry(root, width=40, bd=5, bg="light grey", fg="dark grey")
entry_id.insert(0, "Local ID")
entry_id.grid(row=2, column=1)
...
label_note = Label(root, text="Note:")
label_note.grid(row=14, column=0)

label_msg = Label(root, text="----- no message -----")
label_msg.grid(row=14, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='w')

label = Label(root)

mainloop()
```

What could be my problem?
I will try the suggestion to periodically do `root.update()`.

Comment: The "..." in the code is a bit suspicious. If we remove that but otherwise run your code as-is, do you get the behavior you describe?

Comment: Why do you import tkinter twice in different ways? Is this all of your code? Because there is no other window with the title YES in that code.

Comment: This is not all the code but it is the main part of the big window the other is just yes notification with ok button. I just wanted to show you how it looks when it loses the information! I guess the double import of tkinter is not needed.

Comment: I can't reproduce problem on `Linux Mint` but code in question doesn't have code to create second window  with title `Yes`. Maybe it runs some long-running code and it can't refresh window when it go back from other screen. It may need to run code in separated thread or code may need to run periodically `root.update()` to periodically update window.